# google map javascript does not render properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I must be making a simple mistake. I cannot get a minimal google V3 map to display. Below is my code. What I am seeing are vertical columns of the map that repeat, with blank spaces in between.

```
function hajj_map_view() {

    var mapDiv = jQuery('#hajj-map');

    if ( !mapDiv.length )
            return;

    function show_map(listing_location) {
            var mapProp = {
                center:listing_location,
                zoom:5,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("hajj-map"), mapProp);


            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map
            });

            //map.setCenter(listing_location);
            marker.setPosition(listing_location);
    }

    show_map(new google.maps.LatLng('21.422', '39.826'));
}
```

Comment: why are you setting the center twice? You have already done so when you create the new google map.

Comment: Yes, setting the center is redundant, But it shouldn't matter, right? I have removed it and still see the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is forced by the format `max-width:50px` for `article.listing img` . This selector also matches the images inside the map(e.g. the tiles, which will be limited to a width of 50px, but does have a real width of 256px).

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
#hajj-map img{max-width:none;}
```